# how can i use jquery inside wordpress ajax action function?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I am trying to submit the information of a form through ajax in WordPress and I need to check if the user's mobile number has already been registered when submitting the information. And if it was previously registered, an alert box will appear on the screen. But inside the function on the php side you can not use jquery. Many thanks to those who guide me.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    jQuery( 'form[name="contact-me"]' ).on( 'submit', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var form_data = jQuery( this ).serializeArray();
        $.post(zt_send_form_obj.ajax_url, {
            action:      "zt_save_campain_form_data",
            _ajax_nonce:   zt_send_form_obj.nonce,
            values: form_data
        }, function(data) {
            if (data.search('yes')) {
                console.log("form save");
            }
            else{
                console.log("not working");
            }
        });
    });
});
```

```html
<div id="camp_section">
            <div id="form_section">
                <h3><?php echo get_the_title( $post_id );?></h3>
                <div>
                    <img src="<?php echo $campain_data['img']?>">
                </div>
                <p>برای شرکت در کپین ما حتما همه اسپانسر های این کمپین را فالو کنید</p>
                <form id="campain_form" action="" method="post" name="contact-me">
                    <input type="text" name="name_lastname" id="name_lastname" class="camp_form_input" placeholder="نام و نام خانوادگی خود را وارد نمایید">
                    <input type="text" name="instagram_id" id="instagram_id" class="camp_form_input" placeholder="آیدی اینستاگرام خود را وارد نمایید">
                    <input type="number" name="phone_num" id="phone_num" class="camp_form_input" placeholder="شماره موبایل خود را وارد نمایید">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="protocol" id="protocol" class="camp_form_input" required>
                    <label for="protocol">من <a href="#">قوانین شرکت در مسابقه</a> را مطالعه کرده و قبول دارم</label>
                    <input type="hidden" name="form_id" value="<?php echo $post_id;?>">
                    <button type="submit" id="form_submit">تکمیل ثبت نام در مسابقه</button>
                    
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
```

```php
add_action('wp_ajax_zt_save_campain_form_data',function() {
    check_ajax_referer('title_send_nonce');
    if($_POST==""){return ;}
    $value = $_POST['values'];
    $which_form = $value[4]['value'];
    $register_mobiles = get_post_meta($which_form, 'register_mobiles_list',true);
    if(in_array($value[1]['value'] , $register_mobiles) || in_array($value[2]['value'] , $register_mobiles)){
        ?>
        <script>
            jQuery(document).ready(function($){
                $('#camp_section').append('<div>some text</div>');
            });
        </script>
        <?php
        
    }
    else{
    $camp_data=get_post_meta($which_form, 'campain_data',true);
    $last_code=get_post_meta($which_form, 'last_code',true);
    $last_code++;
    update_post_meta($which_form, 'last_code' , $last_code);
    $user_data= array(
        'name'=>$value[0]['value'], 
        'instagram_id'=>$value[1]['value'],
        'mobile'=>$value[2]['value'],
        'user_code'=>$last_code
    );
    array_push($register_mobiles,$value[1]['value']);
    array_push($register_mobiles,$value[2]['value']);
    update_post_meta($which_form, 'user_info_'.$last_code , $user_data);
    update_post_meta($which_form, 'register_mobiles_list' , $register_mobiles);
    var_dump($register_mobiles);
    }
});
```

Comment: Hello, Welcome to SO! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), and [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page. Inside `wp_ajax_zt_save_campain_form_data` function, once you've found a registered user, send response back to Ajax and do the JQuery inside Ajax?

Comment: Hello, thanks for your guidance.
yes I want to in this part if my condition was true then jquery execute.

 if(in_array($value[1]['value'] , $register_mobiles) || in_array($value[2]['value'] , $register_mobiles)){
        ?>
        <script>
            jQuery(document).ready(function($){
                $('#camp_section').append('<div>some text</div>');
            });
        </script>
        <?php
        
    }
Is such this thing possible?

Comment: In general, I want a message to appear on the page when a user has already registered. If the method I have chosen is wrong, please tell me what should I do?